# Regex - get string between special character

Tags: javascript, regex

This is blank text:

```
[Tiền Giang] DB: 092743 1: 99578 2: 09593 3: 93933 - 17703 4: 04433 - 62172 - 47622 - 95029 - 80836 - 15012 - 30888 [Kiên Giang] DB: 564242 1: 03204 2: 49541 3: 79330 - 49374 4: 84491 - 10327 - 95832 - 61630 - 90692 - 28793 - 28600
```

I want get:

```
(0) [Tiền Giang] 
(1) DB: 092743 1: 99578 2: 09593 3: 93933 - 17703 4: 04433 - 62172 - 47622 - 95029 - 80836 - 15012 - 30888 
(0) [Kiên Giang] 
(1) DB: 564242 1: 03204 2: 49541 3: 79330 - 49374 4: 84491 - 10327 - 95832 - 61630 - 90692 - 28793 - 28600
```

...

I was get (0) with : `(\[(.*?)\]\s).exec(text)`;
but with (1) any idea..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do it using 2 captured groups.

```js
var str = "[Tiền Giang] DB: 092743 1: 99578 2: 09593 3: 93933 - 17703 4: 04433 - 62172 - 47622 - 95029 - 80836 - 15012 - 30888 [Kiên Giang] DB: 564242 1: 03204 2: 49541 3: 79330 - 49374 4: 84491 - 10327 - 95832 - 61630 - 90692 - 28793 - 28600 ";
var pattern = /(\[.+?])([^[]+)/g;
var matches;

while ((matches = pattern.exec(str)) !== null) {
    console.log("(0) " + matches[1]);
    console.log("(1) " + matches[2]);
}
```

- Group 1: The brackets and the characters `(\[.+?\])`
- Group 2: Continuing until you encounter an [ `([^[]+)`